# Linking to C in Microsoft developer studio 2000 Fortran powerstation v 4

Tags: c++, c, interface, linker, fortran

I am trying a test build of some old code (hence the old compiler). I need to link C and F files, but I am getting the following error

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _flow

for each mention of a C file in the F code. Below is an example of how the f files link to the C files.

```
  INTERFACE

    SUBROUTINE flow (from, to, when, howmuch)
      !MS$ATTRIBUTES C, ALIAS:'_flow' :: flow
      REAL from
      REAL to
      REAL when
      REAL howmuch
    END SUBROUTINE flow

  END INTERFACE
```

I am struggling to find any suggestions for the compiler I am using, but I suspect that the code is OK (I am assured the model has built from this code previously) and there is something wrong with what I am doing- I am wondering if I don't have the appropriate libraries to tell the compiler I am trying to link to C? I did attempt to download `fortran.h` and add this to my project file but this did not help, and when I added

```
include 'fortran.h'
```

to the relevant f files it caused syntax errors.

here is also the `fortran.h` file I am using

// Definitions for calling FORTRAN 77 from C++

```
typedef int     INTEGER;          // INTEGER              4 bytes
typedef float   REAL;             // REAL                 4 bytes
typedef double  DOUBLE_PRECISION; // DOUBLE PRECISION     8 bytes
typedef int     LOGICAL;          // LOGICAL              4 bytes

#include  <f77char.h>             // character            n bytes
#include  <f77cmplx.h>            // complex
#include  <f77matrx.h>            // fmatrix class

// values for LOGICAL
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1

// Macros for portable handling of linkage and calling conventions
//#ifdef F77_STUB_REQUIRED
// Typically, this branch is for Unix computers

// C++ stub functions:
#define SUBROUTINE                    inline void
#define INTEGER_FUNCTION              inline INTEGER
#define REAL_FUNCTION                 inline REAL
#define LOGICAL_FUNCTION              inline LOGICAL
#define DOUBLE_PRECISION_FUNCTION     inline DOUBLE_PRECISION

// FORTRAN functions
#define SUBROUTINE_F77                extern "C" void
#define INTEGER_FUNCTION_F77          extern "C" int
#define REAL_FUNCTION_F77             extern "C" float
#define LOGICAL_FUNCTION_F77          extern "C" int
#define DOUBLE_PRECISION_FUNCTION_F77 extern "C" double

//#endif

// Array indexing differences between C++ and fortran
//#define B(i)  b[i-1]
```

Thanks for reading- help greatly appreciated, and let me know if more information would be useful!

Comment: This accidentally ended up in ColdFusion (since removed). You may want to add back some "c" related tags.

Comment: Yeah, don't use that header file, it will make too many holes in the punch card.  This is a linker error, not a compiler error, you probably forgot to tell the fortran linker to link the .obj file generated by the C compiler.  Or you actually wrote C++ code instead of C.  There has to be somebody at this company you work for, old guy with a gray beard, that can point his finger after looking for 30 seconds and say "Here!"

Comment: Thanks, linker error fixed! I now only have 3 unresolved errors  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __getstdfilex             error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __max                     error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __min        I am thinking I have a header file missing, but I can't seem to find a header that contains these- any advice? sadly, the code is provided from another institution, and there is zero tech suport for this sort of thing at work.......

Comment: Do you know whether max and min are from C or Fortran?  FYI, if you  click on Help/Search - and search for Mixed, you will find help on mixel language programming.

Comment: @cup The OP was last seen in 2013, so I wouldn't expect too much (I wasn't the one who activated this post).